# Android Sound Drop Down Menu - Volume Buttons Broken

Tags: volume-buttons

As displayed in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdQ83.png) is there a sound control for Android notification/drop down menu?

Alternatively some other mechanism.  The volume buttons are broken on my phone.

Ideally well rated app.

Comment: If you are looking to add sound tile, try out this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles

Comment: @beeshyams do you know of a different app it links to separate controls

Comment: You can try this. I haven't used it ever https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.claudio.chimera.virtualvolume

Comment: Or this open source, well rated app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punksta.apps.volumecontrol

Comment: Did any of these help?

Comment: Help yes not ideal from a lock screen though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works from the lock screen https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.phhuang.volumecontrol